# Is there any trick to implement floating label for dropdown and datepicker components in Angular Dart?

Tags: dart, angular-components, angular-dart

Is there any trick to implement ***floating label*** for `material-dropdown-select` and `material-datepicker` components in Angular Dart, like has to `material-input`?

We *have* here: `Floating label` in [AngularDart Gallery - Material Input Demo](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#MaterialInputDemoComponentDemo)

Here with AngularJs Material: `Enter date` dropdown in [Demos - Input](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input). Example: [image]

But this behavior we *do not have* here:

`...DemoComponent` in [AngularDart Gallery - Material Dropdown Selection](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_dropdown_select)

`...DemoComponent` in [AngularDart Gallery - Material Datepicker](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_datepicker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry our enterprise UX didn't want the floating label in their designs and so it was never implemented. If the UX team changes their mind we will add them, but so far they are happy with the current design.

Comment: I can not understand the real reason for not having a floating label for these components, but I also understand and appreciate very much that the design specifications are being followed and respected. As everything in this world with time is improved, I believe that at some point in the future this will be reviewed. For now, I am using a combination of `<label>` with these components, plus CSS to change the color when they receive the focus. It is not floating, but at first it is acceptable.